# Adding more than one row to an array inside componentDidMount for loop

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Im trying to add more than one item into this array but I'm not sure how to do so, any feedback is appreciated!

```
async componentDidMount() {

for (i = 0; i < this.state.permissionsResponseData.length; i++) {
                if (this.state.permissionsResponseData[i].role_id === this.state.roleResponseDataID.id) {
                    await this.setState({
                        accessRoleData: this.state.permissionsResponseData[i].data
                    })
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: About what array are u talking?

Comment: @VaganM. `accessRoleData`  this is how im initializing it `state = { accessRoleData: []}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few changes you need to do here.

First change, **setState** is not an async function, so you should remove the `await`

```
 await this.setState({
```

I'm correct to assume the `accessRoleData` is an array?

If it's and you want to add items there, you can use the `prevState` from `setState` method, ,like:

```
 this.setState((prevState) => ({
      accessRoleData: [...prevState.accessRoleData, this.state.permissionsResponseData[i].data]
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Yeh `accessRoleData` is an array, after adding your changes I get the following warning `Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'i'`

Comment: Just change ‘for(i=‘ by ‘for(let i=‘

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
   accessRoleData: [...prevState.accessRoleData, 
             this.state.permissionsResponseData[i].data]
}))
```

Comment: some comments with the code would help understand better.